# How do I remarshal a modified message with ActiveMQ (OpenWire)?

Tags: activemq-classic, marshalling

First a little explanation of what I'm trying to do. I am writing a Java (1.7) application that will attempt to "fuzz" XML messages sent over ActiveMQ, using the OpenWire format from a producer to a target consumer. The intent is to gauge how the target responds to the fuzzed messages sent to it. I am using ActiveMQ version 5.12.1 on Linux CentOS 6.6.

There is an XML schema which defines the message types that will be sent. I have separate programs that generate sample instances of these messages and identifies where information is found in the wire format sent (OpenWire in this case). This information will be used in the fuzzing process to know the location of the data to change.

Part of the fuzzing process involves capturing the wire format message off the wire, making the change and forwarding the modified message on to the target. I have been able to successfully modify data and send it forward, as long as I have changed only content and not length. If the modification results in a change in length, the connection to the ActiveMQ server closes and the program fails.

Research indicates that the OpenWire messages all start with a 4 byte integer, representing the length of the following message data. I changed my code to adjust that length to reflect the change made to the test data. That did not work. After some more investigation, I discovered that just changing the length field was not the right thing to do - but it was not obvious what should (or could) be done.

I'm getting a strong impression, that the best thing to do would be to use the ActiveMQ API to re-marshal the modified message data and forward that on to the target. I have no idea if that's an option available to me.

I've tried to find information to help me determine the structure of the OpenWire messages involved so that I can know what I need to do when modifying the message. I started looking at the ActiveMQ javadocs and found the openwire packages. Perhaps I can utilize these to effect the changes I need to make and to have them successfully forwarded via ActiveMQ and received by the target.

Is there any documentation or sample code that provides instruction or examples of how to properly use this API to do what I need? Based on what I've described, is this something that is doable using the API? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://camel.apache.org
There is no need to interpret the wire format directly.
Can even run in amq server.

Comment: First, I know nothing about Camel. How would I get around "knowing" the wire format? I need to be able to do something like: replace message field A content "ABC" with new content "XYZ", where the message is defined by an XML schema. Obviously that is a very simple scenario. I either need to figure out where field A's content is in the wire format, or I would need something that helps me make that replacement. Can Camel do (or assist with) that sort of thing?

Comment: In camel there are „routes“ to help you there. You can get the msg off the queue, unmarshal, change,marshal and send to another queue. The input format (byte, text, object) on the queue is determined by your sender.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to send Xml data over ActiveMQ.

1. You don't need to worry about Openwire. The client libraries handle that for you. That is the protocol that the ActiveMQ JMS library uses to talk to ActiveMQ, while your program only has to worry about how to talk JMS.
2. Decide what API to use to talk to ActiveMQ.. if it is Java, use the JMS API and send a TextMessage object where the body is set to the string representation of the Xml data. If it is C#, look at ActiveMQ's NMS library. If PHP/Python/Perl or other scripting language, look for STOMP libraries and send Text messages with the Xml data as the body.